# Use self signed and trusted certificates at the same time in git

Tags: git, ssl, git-clone

I setup my own git server with self signed certificate. My `.gitconfig` looks like this

```
[credential]
    helper = wincred
[http]
    sslCAInfo = path-to-my-certificate
```

It is working for my own git server. However, I get an error when I cloned another https git repository

```
fatal: unable to access     
'https://url-of-git': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

it is working fine after I remove the ssl configuration.

How should I solve my problem to use self-singed and trusted certificate at the same time? Thanks for any suggestions.

BTW: I have tested it in windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 with the similar errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your sslCAInfo *only* for your server

```
git config http.https://yourserver.sslCAInfo path-to-my-certificate
```

That will give a config like:

```
[http "https://yourserver"]
    sslCAInfo = path-to-my-certificate
```

That path will only apply when you are using a remote with a specific url.

See [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more:

```
http.<url>.*
```

> Any of the `http.*` options above can be applied selectively to some URLs. For a config key to match a URL, each element of the config key is compared to that of the URL